# Prefetch frames works only at opening blend-file?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

On opening a 2.91 Blend-file in the video sequencer, I can see that the "prefetch frames" kicks in. A small orange line starts from the playhead and keeps going until the cache buffer is full (I assume). Previewing the video (for that range) runs then very smoothly. However, after that initial prefetch, it seems that the cache is dismissed and/or not renewed and that the prefetch doesn't kick in any more. Previewing the video becomes then very slow.

I have tried to switch the prefetch option on and off, or changing the field "Recycle up to Cost" (default 10) but that doesn't help. I'm not sure what the "strip cache option" (per strip) does in surplus, but it also does not reset the prefetch frames option.

Am I missing something here? Is there any up-to-date information about the VSE caching (aside from https://developer.blender.org/D3934)?

Comment: In Preferences - System you can set the cache limit.
Maybe Ctrl+R(Refresh All) will restart cache.
Cache todo: https://developer.blender.org/T80278

Answer (score 0):

Changing the cache limit size or the cache type (use disk cache), Ctrl+R (or Alt+R) does not reinitialize the prefetch cache. The only work-around so far is saving the file and re-open it. At that moment the prefetch kicks in, the little orange stripe at the bottom keeps growing from the play head and (after a while) the preview runs smoothly again. This keeps on working until you change something in the timeline. Then the orange cache bar dims out and the performance drops to a much lower frame rate. Apparently, this is also the case in version 2.83 and 2.90.